# Why every new file is automatically encoded with ASCII while everything is set to UTF-8?

Tags: command-line, vim, locale

My system locale is set to UTF-8:US, this is confirmed by running the locale command. But it is very strange that every time I type the `vim FILENAME` command (the file does not exist, I'm using this command to create a new file), and I use `:wq` to save the file, I always get file coded in ASCII. I tried to add the line `set fileencodings=utf-8` in the .vimrc file, but nothing changed. How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 3):

When all your chars are `< 128` ASCII and UTF-8 are the same.
ASCII is a subset of UTF-8 (and also a subset of latin1 and many other encoding formats).

**Probably everything is perfect!**

---

The configuration command:

`set fileencodings=`*list of encoding formats to try*

is used to define the order of encoding format that vim will try to
use when opening 
a file.

`set fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf-8,latin1` is a better idea: first try
to use any Unicode with a `BOM` header, then it will try to interpret it as `UTF-8`, and if everything fails `latin1`.

Comment: I think this is correct, as I just created two files with `vim`, one containing a single `a` and one containing a random UTF-8 character; `file 1` outputs `1: ASCII text`, `file 2` outputs `2: UTF-8 Unicode text`. So it looks like the encoding is set based on the smallest character set containing the set of characters actually used.

Comment: @kos, thank for the experiment. It makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

In your .vimrc, add

```
set encoding=utf-8
```

and restart Vim. See [Documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27encoding%27).